# Appending to current route in Backbone/Marionette?

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, marionette

I have a part of my Marionette app that I am opening a bootstrap modal. When this happens, I want to register it opening as a "navigate" event, for which I am currently using `App.navigate("/modal",false);` to change the url. In the modal view I am listening for the back history event to close the modal (Useful for Android / mobile), but I would like to *append* "/modal" to the current route, instead of it be the root.

How can I get the current Route/URL to then append "/modal" to and call the .navigate() function on?

Thanks!

EDIT:

Apparently the phrase I was looking for here, in terms of web development, is a "micro-state", as explained at the blog here: http://chrisawren.com/posts/Implementing-microstates-in-Backbone-js

The approach suggested is to bypass the backbone history altogether and directly interface with the html5 history stack, for places where you need a fullscreen modal but don't want to invoke the router handling or change the URL, but still want to support the back button.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply

`router.navigate(router.fragment + "/modal")`

Comment: Too simple! Hahaha. To fully implement this, I apparently already had an `App.getCurrentRoute()` function in my app.js, probably from the "Gentle Introduction to Marionette" book. This returns `Backbone.history.fragment`, which is the right fragment you're referring to.

Comment: In further research, it turns out "microstates" was the key phrase I needed to search, and I found a blog that explains a way to implement what I was actually looking for. However, since you did a great job of answering my question as stated, (and I've implemented this for now), I've marked this as the answer

Comment: Glad to help, that should be a new feature, it has been 1 year without touching backbone. I recall despite this `fragment` thing was a very common case it wasn't documented